# how to compute diff for one col in spark dataframe?

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
+-------------------+
|           Dev_time|
+-------------------+
|2015-09-18 05:00:20|
|2015-09-18 05:00:21|
|2015-09-18 05:00:22|
|2015-09-18 05:00:23|
|2015-09-18 05:00:24|
|2015-09-18 05:00:25|
|2015-09-18 05:00:26|
|2015-09-18 05:00:27|
|2015-09-18 05:00:37|
|2015-09-18 05:00:37|
|2015-09-18 05:00:37|
|2015-09-18 05:00:38|
|2015-09-18 05:00:39|
+-------------------+
```

For spark's dataframe, I want to compute the diff of the datetime ,just like in `numpy.diff(array)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try to help. This is a very low quality question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking there is no efficient way to achieve this using Spark `DataFrames`. Not to mention things like order become quite tricky in a distributed setup. Theoretically you can use `lag` function as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col, unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

dev_time = (unix_timestamp(col("dev_time")) * 1000).cast("timestamp")

df = sc.parallelize([
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:20", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:21", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:22", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:23", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:24", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:25", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:26", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:27", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:37", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:37", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:37", ), ("2015-09-18 05:00:38", ),
    ("2015-09-18 05:00:39", )
]).toDF(["dev_time"]).withColumn("dev_time", dev_time)

w = Window.orderBy("dev_time")
lag_dev_time = lag("dev_time").over(w).cast("integer")

diff = df.select((col("dev_time").cast("integer") - lag_dev_time).alias("diff"))

## diff.show()
## +----+
## |diff|
## +----+
## |null|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |   1|
## |  10|
## ...
```

but it is extremely inefficient (as for window functions move all data to a single partition if no `PARTITION BY` clause is provided). In practice it makes more sense to use `sliding` method  on a RDD (Scala) or implement your own sliding window (Python). See:

- [How to transform data with sliding window over time series data in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685714/1560062)
- [How to access Spark RDD Array of elements based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33598541/1560062)

Comment: How about If use approxCountDistinct function?

Comment: @giaosudau How does it help?

Comment: Yeah. Because It implement hyperloglog algorithms? More efficient when counting the distinct as I think. I am not sure about that just asking.

Comment: @giaosudau What I mean is how counting distinct elements helps  with computing difference over timeseries?

Comment: Sorry I just think simple is he want to count distinct of the datetime. So I think just using the DataFrame Function.

Comment: @giaosudau If thats the case then sure. But I don't think this is the goal here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99770/discussion-between-giaosudau-and-zero323).