# How to apply multiple methods at a time in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

df is a dataframe contains all car data(| id | time | speed | gps |...|);

trips is a series list contains(id,start,end) which generate from df.

method1 is used to get each id's stats information.
method2 is used to get each id's other stats information.

Like this code:

```
val a = method1(trips,df,sc)
val b = method2(trips,df,sc)
val c = method3(trips,df,sc)
val d = method4(trips,df,sc)
val e = method5(trips,df,sc)
val f = method6(trips,df,sc)
```

Because each method take a certain time, is there any way to apply the methods for assignments at the same time?
The type of a,b...,f is dataframe.

Comment: Are the type signatures the same?

Comment: yes, the type signatures are same

Comment: @zero323 spark runs operations in parallel anyway, because the calls are lazy - unless you collect somewhere.

Comment: @zero323 Indeed, each method have to do series work(dataframe filter,select and compute after dataframe.collect() )

Comment: @steven can't do without collect?

Comment: It's hard to do without collect action; Because I have to do datetime diff for one column(time) , there is no available method in spark api now. The purpose to do this is to divide the whole data into trips based on drive time. Is it possible to use akka.actor method to achieve my target？

Comment: @steven you could write an UDAF. It's a bit hairy though.

Comment: @steven Unless it is a matter of suboptimal resource utilization (small data frames, a lot of resources) it is not worth all the fuss. You can submit jobs asynchronously using futures or parallel maps over functions and force execution but it is usually pointless. Based on your last comment it looks more like XY problem anyway.

Comment: @Reactormonk I aked the problem several days ago. In the last, I take scala sliding method for collect() data.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935363/how-to-compute-datetime-diff-for-one-col-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: Why not use `sliding` on RDD?

Comment: I guess linked to a confusing question there... Take a look at this for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/33598541/1560062

Comment: Also there is a new library from Cloudera:https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries

Comment: @Reactormonk Laziness doesn't really affect parallelism. How different tasks are executed is a matter of DAGs and resource management.

Comment: @zero323 that is correct. But laziness gives Spark the ability to do parallelism for you. If you `collect` in between, you're taking that ability away from Spark.

Comment: @zero323 thank you  and Reactormonk; like you said "You can submit jobs asynchronously using futures or parallel maps over functions and force execution but it is usually pointless", can you give an example about  parallel maps over functions for this.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912858/processing-multiple-files-as-independent-rdds-in-parallel/31916657#31916657 or solution provided by @SandeepPurohit

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run multiple jobs at a same time in spark cluster with the help of asynchronous actions like collectAsync(),countAsync() etc.

```
 yo just set configuration with context .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
```

And use asynchronous actions and so all jobs runs asynchronously and its return future so your methods also return future so all methods run at a time.